# Left join with AND OR conditions need to be enclosed in parentheses

Tags: sql, oracle, left-join

My query is :

```
select * from A left join B on a.id = b.id 
and a. id <> "N/A" and b.id <> "N/A" 
OR 
A.ID = "N/A" AND B.ID = "N/A" AND A.COL2 IS NOT NULL
```

Basically I want to join on the `id` column only when one of these `OR` conditions is fulfilled.
Is this query correct or do I need to include the part in parentheses ?

```
a. id <> "N/A" and b.id "N/A" 
OR 
A.ID = "N/A" AND B.ID = "N/A" AND A.COL2 IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: You have to parenthesize according to your requirement, it gives the reader a context of why a particular condition was written.

Comment: I assume "N/A" is 'N/A', correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`AND` has a higher priority than `OR` (similar to "`*` comes before `+`").

Therefore this expression:

```
a. id <> "N/A" AND b.id <> "N/A" 
OR 
A.ID = "N/A" AND B.ID = "N/A" AND A.COL2 IS NOT NULL
```

... is equivalent to ...

```
(a. id <> "N/A" AND b.id <> "N/A")
OR 
(A.ID = "N/A" AND B.ID = "N/A" AND A.COL2 IS NOT NULL)
```

But because `a.id = b.id` should always be true, you must at least place one pair of parentheses

```
SELECT * FROM A LEFT JOIN B ON 
  a.id = b.id AND 
  (
    a. id <> "N/A" AND b.id <> "N/A" 
    OR 
    A.ID = "N/A" AND B.ID = "N/A" AND A.COL2 IS NOT NULL
  )
```